# Improving GPRS Internet Performance

Tags: routing, internet, connection, internet-connection, gprs

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. But since it is related to GPRS network infrastructure and somewhat packet routing I'm placing it here. Do correct me if I am wrong!

I used to access internet with a GPRS enabled USB modem. With this when trying to accessing webpages it used to be very slow. It was like something was blocking the flow of this packets. It was like the data transfer is getting blocked in between each packets are sent.

Once out of curiosity I had a metaphorical thought that it may be because packets are having difficulty in finding paths for them each time a packet is sent.

I just ran a `ping ip-address` in my terminal in the background , to my amusement the webpage started loading much faster and in more progressive manner as the ping application continuously pings to that ip-address.
I tried repeating this many times. Whenever some page takes unusually long time for loading, i just run this ping trick and the situation improves!

I am totally confused in this is just coincidence ( I'm pretty sure it's not since i tried it quite a number of times now! ) or is there any theoretical reason behind this. If this ping packets are making the packet flow easier or anything like that!

Sorry if you think this was just me having a day dream!

Comment: How is this a server problem?

Comment: I thought this forum wasnt exclusively about server problem. Also it indirectly about why the server responds differently in two situations! 
Infact I could find a more suitable stack exchange website to post this!

Comment: Should read the FAQ, then. "Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a **professional capacity**."

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a DNS issue to me, as when you resolve the hostname with a ping the website loads quickly.

Which DNS server are you using? Try changing to 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) and see if it is any quicker.

Comment: I use OpenDns Server. 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220
With Google DNS it seems even slower.

Comment: So, out of interest if you browse to http://212.58.244.68 how quick do you find that?

Comment: should be around 25s